# Spring data + Hibernate unexpected @JoinTable behaviour

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have several entities that make up a security control mechanism, some of these entities are simple join tables

The UserAccount entity has a securityGroup field that should contain the groups that the user is assigned to, and the securityGroup entities should have have the security permissions assigned to that group.

The test user is assigned to 3 security groups, and the security groups have a varying number of permissions.
The expected behaviour was that the securityGroup collection field in the user object would have 3 securityGroup objects and the securityGroup objects would have their respective permissions.

The actual behaviour is that the securityGroup field in the user entity has 243 entries which is the total number of permissions assigned to the groups, with each group repeated for the number of permissions assigned to that group.

Could someone please explain how I can change this to obtain the expected behaviour, I am quite new to JPA and so struggling to understand what I may have got wrong.

Thanks

UserAccount enity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_account")
public class UserAccount implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "UUID")
    private String uuid;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

 @JoinTable(name = "user_security_group", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_UUID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "security_group_uuid", unique = true))

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<SecurityGroup> securityGroups;
    // Getters and setters omitted for brevity
```

SecurityGroup entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "security_group")
public class SecurityGroup implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "UUID")
    private String uuid;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
    private String groupId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @JoinTable(name = "security_group_permissions", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID", referencedColumnName = "GROUP_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id", referencedColumnName = "PERMISSION_ID")})
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<SecurityPermission> securityPermissionCollection;
    // Getters and setters omitted for brevity
```

SecurityPermission entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "security_permission")
public class SecurityPermission implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "PERMISSION_ID")
    private String permissionId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    // Getters and setters omitted for brevity
```

The sql for the join tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `security_group_permissions` (
  `GROUP_ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `permission_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`GROUP_ID`,`permission_id`),
  KEY `sgp_p_fk_idx` (`permission_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `sgp_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`GROUP_ID`) REFERENCES `security_group` (`GROUP_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `sgp_p_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`permission_id`) REFERENCES `security_permission` (`PERMISSION_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `security_group` (
  `UUID` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `GROUP_ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UUID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`GROUP_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_security_group` (
  `USER_UUID` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `security_group_uuid` char(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`USER_UUID`,`security_group_uuid`),
  KEY `security_group_fk_idx` (`security_group_uuid`),
  CONSTRAINT `security_group_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`security_group_uuid`) REFERENCES `security_group` (`UUID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `user_sec_grp_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_UUID`) REFERENCES `user_account` (`UUID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that using a Collection to hold the entities was not the correct way to do this.

Having changed the Collection to a Set have given me the expected behaviour.